# Why my Registration ID is not being passed?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

```
public class MessageReceivingService extends Service{
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
     public static SharedPreferences savedValues;

      public static void sendToApp(Bundle extras, Context context){

        Intent newIntent = new Intent();
        newIntent.setClass(context, AndroidMobilePushApp.class);
        newIntent.putExtras(extras);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    }

    public void onCreate(){

        super.onCreate();
        final String preferences = getString(R.string.preferences);
        savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // In later versions multi_process is no longer the default

        if(VERSION.SDK_INT >  9){
            savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        }

        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences savedValues = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 =      savedValues.edit();
        editor1.putBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true);
        editor1.commit();


        if(savedValues.getBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true)){
            register();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), false);
            editor.commit();
        }
        // Let AndroidMobilePushApp know we have just initialized and there may be stored messages
        sendToApp(new Bundle(), this);
    }

    protected static void saveToLog(Bundle extras, Context context){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=savedValues.edit();
        String numOfMissedMessages = context.getString(R.string.num_of_missed_messages);
        int linesOfMessageCount = 0;
        for(String key : extras.keySet()){
            String line = String.format("%s=%s", key, extras.getString(key));
            editor.putString("MessageLine" + linesOfMessageCount, line);
            linesOfMessageCount++;
        }
        editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
        editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
        editor.putInt(numOfMissedMessages, savedValues.getInt(numOfMissedMessages, 0) + 1);
        editor.commit();
        postNotification(new Intent(context, AndroidMobilePushApp.class), context);
    }

    protected static void postNotification(Intent intentAction, Context context){
        final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentAction, Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
        final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Message Received!")
                .setContentText("")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .getNotification();

        mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_number, notification);
    }

    private void register() {

        new AsyncTask(){

            protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {

                String token;
                try {
                    token = gcm.register(getString(R.string.project_number));
                    Log.i("registrationId", token);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Registration Error", "mesgerror " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return true;
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just giving some code does not fully describes your question. Try to add some description.

Comment: When i run the code the registration ID supposed to be appear in the LogCat. But it does not. Thus it means the registration Id value is does being generated by GCM. I got the code directly from Amazon Web Service SNS but it does not work.

Comment: What do you see in your logcat? If you call your `register` method you should see either of your debug prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be for 2 reason:

> 1. You are not getting the registration values.
> 2. Your log is not working.

For case 1: Debug you code ans set some breakpoint to see if you are getting the registration code nr not.

For case 2: You may try restarting the eclips.

Hope this helps.. :)